# How easy is it to make a VB.net form button run logic in a separate thread

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005

I'm not a VB coder but I'm tinkering with a little VB.net utility project which lets you set up a few parameters in a form and hit "go" - this then does a lot of logic which can run for several minutes.

This all happens in the go-button-handler which blocks the form. I wondered, is it easy in vb.net to make all this logic happen in a separate thread which can still update the form i.e. update a label to show which file is being processed? If it's complicated, it's not worth doing in my use-case!

Is it possible to just copy-paste my event code into a thread.Run or something like that, or even dynamically create a thread class around the code I have?

Comment: Look up the threading.thread classes. Should be fairly straight forward if you are used to threading in general.

Comment: this should point you in the right direction.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289178%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have used the BackgroundWorker class (System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker) many times for things like this.  It's very simple to use (compared to other multi-threading techniques available in .NET).  Just drag it from the tool box onto your form, for example.  If you set it's "WorkerReportsProgress" and "WorkerSupportsCancellation" properties to "True", you can even give feedback in your UI in the form of a progress bar, for example, and provide the ability for the user to click the cancel button.

Anyway, there's a lot more information about it than I can reasonably include here, so I would start by looking at this page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

Answer (score 0):

BackgroundWorker is a good choice to start.  Whatever you use be aware that performance can be affected if the background thread is processor intensive i.e. a long running tight loop.  This might not be very obvious if you have a multi-core CPU.

Here is a simple example of Threading.Thread.

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Button3.Enabled = False
    'for example pass a string and an integer to a thread as an array
    Dim params() As Object = {"one", 1} 'parameters for thread. object picked because of mixed type
    Dim t As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf someThread)
    t.IsBackground = True
    t.Start(params) 'start thread with params
End Sub

Public Sub someThread(params As Object)
    'not on the UI
    Dim theparams() As Object = DirectCast(params, Object()) 'convert object to what it really is, an array of objects
    Dim param1 As String = DirectCast(theparams(0), String)
    Dim param2 As Integer = DirectCast(theparams(1), Integer)
    Debug.WriteLine(param1)
    Debug.WriteLine(param2)

    showOnUI(param1)
End Sub

Public Sub showOnUI(s As String)
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        'not running on UI
        Me.Invoke(Sub() showOnUI(s)) 'run method on UI
    Else
        'running on UI
        Label1.Text = s
        Button3.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```